# Given a blob hash, can I find the tree(s) which point to it?

Tags: git, sha

XY problem:

I ran `git show <filepath>` to see the current version of a file. But I'm a bit confused by the output:

```
commit <abc1234...> (HEAD -> <branch>)
Author: <Fname Lname> <fname.lname@email.com>
Date:   <Date>

    <Commit message>

diff --git a/<filepath> b/<filepath>
index bcd4567..dedbeef 100644
--- a/<filepath>
+++ b/<filepath>
```

It's telling me that `git show` is showing me a `diff` of something, between `bcd4567` and `dedbeef`. I want to know what these hashes are referring to. I know that I can use `git cat-file -t <hash>` to see the type of object these hashes are referring to (they're blobs) and I can use `git cat-file -p <hash>` to see the object themselves. So I know what file they are referring to. What I don't know is which **version** of the file they're referring to.

So there are two questions here. The direct question is:

1. What does the line `index bcd4567..dedbeef 100644` refer to in the `git show` output? What versions of a file is it showing me? Is it showing the difference between the work tree and the index, or something else?

And more generally:

2. Given a situation where I have an unknown hash and want to know *where it comes from*, how can I discover this? Is there a command that will allow me to find e.g. all tree objects which point to a given hash, or to discover all the names (branch, tag, etc.) that a hash has been given?

Answer (score 1):

`git show <filepath>` is equivalent to `git show HEAD <filepath>`. It prints the changes between `filepath` of HEAD's parent and `filepath` of HEAD.

In `index bcd4567..dedbeef 100644`, `bcd4567` is the blob hash of `filepath` in HEAD's parent and `dedbeef` is the blob hash of `filepath` in HEAD. You could add `--full-index` to show full hash.

If you know a blob hash, you could try `git log --all --find-object=<blobhash>` to find which commits introduce or remove(not sure) the blob.

To find all the tree objects that reference the blob, you could first list all the tree objects,

```
git cat-file --batch-all-objects --batch-check | grep tree
```

and then inspect them one by one to find out which references the blob directly.

```
git ls-tree $treehash | grep $blobhash
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you have written the `git show` command, without providing anything else other than the path of the file, then the 2 commits involved are `HEAD~` and `HEAD`. So if you check the object IDs for that file in each revision (with `git ls-tree`, for example) you should see that one commit has `bcd4567` and the other `dedbeef`.